# Can't remove value in registry

Tags: vb.net, registry, visual-studio-2017

I created a registry key value:

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "TestApp", "C:\myapp.exe")
```

Works good, value is in the registry. I tried to delete it with

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run").DeleteValue("TestApp")
```

and

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\TestApp")
```

It does not work. I'm getting an error: "Value does not exist"... But the value exists in my registry.

How do i delete the value ( but not the key)? Any ideas?

Comment: this is VBA ? not sure what exactly is "delete" value means ?

Comment: Visual Basic i using this tutorial (part: 3): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b22e94c-37a9-4be5-ad55-3d9229220194/how-to-use-add-read-change-delete-registry-keys-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Thanks. OpenSubKey need a True (second parametr) if you need write access to the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSubKey set to true if  you need write access to the key, for example if you want delete value:

Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", **True**).DeleteValue("Value to delete")